# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported MVCspring

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

I am creating a web app with spring mvc and i m a beginner.so my app is a simple login application based on this tutorial :
https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/spring/spring-mvc-login-form-example.html

when i run the application  there is an error shown:

```
État HTTP 405 – Method Not Allowed


Type Rapport d''état

message Request method 'GET' not supported

description La méthode HTTP spécifiée n''est pas autorisée pour la ressource demandée.
```

Comment: Please post your full code

Answer (score 0):

Check if login form action method is `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

this is my login controller:

```
package com.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String init(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Please Enter Your Login Details");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(Model model, @ModelAttribute("loginBean") LoginBean loginBean) {
        if (loginBean != null && loginBean.getUserName() != null & loginBean.getPassword() != null) {
            if (loginBean.getUserName().equals("chandra") && loginBean.getPassword().equals("chandra123")) {
                model.addAttribute("msg", loginBean.getUserName());
                return "success";
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid Details");
                return "login";
            }
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Please enter Details");
            return "login";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide your full code, it would be more helpful to answer the question.
Maybe you mistake in several place.

1. Your form is post method, so your action method must be post type. like this,

   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
2. Check your form is `method="post"` or not. By default, form method is `method="get"`